# Reading File Direction/Path Java

Tags: java, logging

I want to read the path of a file. All I've found is about the class file, how to read the file or how to save the file in this direction.

But what I want is a method that shows me the path like this:

*C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/NetBeansProjects/HashmapDemo/HeaderTemplate*

So that i can save this direction in a XML file.

I hope it is understandable what I mean, I tend to write things nobody can understand.

I've tried:

```
    public static String getCleanPath() {
    ClassLoader classLoader = XmlLoader.class.getClassLoader();
    File classpathRoot = new File(classLoader.getResource("").getPath());

    return classpathRoot.getPath();
}
```

So far but like I said, it doesn't give me the information I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the [getAbsoulePath()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getAbsolutePath%28%29) method is what you are looking for?

> `public String getAbsolutePath()`
>
> Returns the absolute pathname string of this abstract pathname.
>
> If this abstract pathname is already absolute, then the pathname
>   string is simply returned as if by the getPath() method. If this
>   abstract pathname is the empty abstract pathname then the pathname
>   string of the current user directory, which is named by the system
>   property user.dir, is returned. Otherwise this pathname is resolved in
>   a system-dependent way. On UNIX systems, a relative pathname is made
>   absolute by resolving it against the current user directory. On
>   Microsoft Windows systems, a relative pathname is made absolute by
>   resolving it against the current directory of the drive named by the
>   pathname, if any; if not, it is resolved against the current user
>   directory.
>
> **Returns:** The absolute pathname string denoting the same file or
>   directory as this abstract pathname

Comment: That's exactly what I've searched for!
Thank you very much!